# SignalR performance is not stable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, refresh, signalr, signalr-hub

I have been using SignalR in my mvc4 asp.net application in order to update Views and have real Time aspect without having to get back to database each time to check states.

The code I integrated in my web api controller and views is working perfectly while debugging. However, I usually get cases where no refresh take place.

I can't seem to figure out the reasons behind such behaviour ( sometimes it works instantly and others not ). I have been relating it to internet connection problems but it seems that it isn't the only fact.

Any ideas or reflexions to keep in mind while using SignalR ?

Answer (score 0):

check for following

`Maximum concurrent requests per CPU
Request queue limit
Maximum requests per application
DefaultMessageBufferSize`

one of these may be blocking the request. 
Reference: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance

Comment: Thanks for the reference but as I can tell this configuration works for IIS .. however my solution is deployed on Azure ..